# Grouping in analytical query

Tags: sql-server, oracle

**I have a table which return records like :**

```
Name   Total_Case_Count   User_Case_Count   P_Count  Rej_Count  PPP_Count    Other_Count

ABC        20                  10            03
ABC        20                  10                      05 
ABC        20                  10                                 02 
XYZ        20                  10            05
XYZ        20                  10                      02
XYZ        20                  10                                 01
XYZ        20                  10                                             02
```

**But I need result like this :**

```
 Name   Total_Case_Count   User_Case_Count   P_Count  Rej_Count  PPP_Count    Other_Count

 ABC        20                  10            03           05       02
 XYZ        20                  10            05           02       01        02
```

**means sum of user count & other count will come in same row. I'm using this query:**

```
    select distinct result.NAME, result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,Total_Case_Count,User_Case_COUNT,Pending_Case_Count,
            Rejected_Case_Count,Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,Active_Case_Count FROM
(
select row_number() over (order by C.CASE_ID asc) as row_index,
   UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
   UA.FIRST_NAME ||' '||UA.LAST_NAME AS NAME,
   COUNT(*) OVER () Total_Case_Count,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) User_Case_COUNT,

   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 2 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 4 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Rejected_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 6 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Active_Case_Count
FROM CASE C 
INNER JOIN CASE_STATUS CS ON CS.CASE_STATUS_ID = C.CASE_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN SSO.USER_ACCOUNTS UA ON UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = C.CREATED_BY 
inner join sso.User_In_Types uit on uit.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID 
inner join SSO.USER_TYPES  ut on UT.USER_TYPE_ID = UiT.USER_TYPE_ID 
where UT.APPLICATION_ID = 12 and UT.USER_TYPE_ID = 2170
) result 
ORDER BY NAME
```

**Any suggestion really appreciated..**

Comment: Why do you use window functions, If you in fact just need to group by your User_Account_id and First_name?

Comment: @lonic : I have single column case_status which I need to be show as a seperate column. See the case I put inside query.

Comment: Ah ok. Well then just put the group by and the aggregation in the outer select. This will solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation in the outer `select`:

```
select result.NAME, result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,MAX(Total_Case_Count),MAX(User_Case_COUNT),MAX(Pending_Case_Count),
            MAX(Rejected_Case_Count),MAX(Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count),MAX(Active_Case_Count) FROM
(
select row_number() over (order by C.CASE_ID asc) as row_index,
   UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID,
   UA.FIRST_NAME ||' '||UA.LAST_NAME AS NAME,
   COUNT(*) OVER () Total_Case_Count,
   COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) User_Case_COUNT,

   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 2 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 4 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Rejected_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID = 6 THEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Pending_For_Payment_Case_Count,
   CASE 
            WHEN C.CASE_STATUS_ID In (1,3,5,7,8,9) THEN  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY C.CASE_STATUS_ID,UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID) end as Active_Case_Count
FROM CASE C 
INNER JOIN CASE_STATUS CS ON CS.CASE_STATUS_ID = C.CASE_STATUS_ID
INNER JOIN SSO.USER_ACCOUNTS UA ON UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = C.CREATED_BY 
inner join sso.User_In_Types uit on uit.USER_ACCOUNT_ID = UA.USER_ACCOUNT_ID 
inner join SSO.USER_TYPES  ut on UT.USER_TYPE_ID = UiT.USER_TYPE_ID 
where UT.APPLICATION_ID = 12 and UT.USER_TYPE_ID = 2170
) result 
GROUP BY result.NAME, result.USER_ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: No problem. Nice to help you. :-9

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question but could you not just use a `group by`?

```
SELECT Name
      ,Total_Case_Count
      ,SUM(User_Case_Count)
      ,SUM(P_Count)
      ,SUM(Rej_Count)          
      ,SUM(PPP_Count)
      ,SUM(Other_Count)
FROM (Your table Here)
GROUP BY Name
        ,Total_Case_Count
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need simple `Group by` with `Aggregate`

```
SELECT Name,
       Total_Case_Count,
       User_Case_Count,
       Max(P_Count),
       Max(Rej_Count),
       Max(PPP_Count),
       Max(Other_Count)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY Name,
          Total_Case_Count,
          User_Case_Count
```